# git bash is doing nothing with "git push" command

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-pages

I am learning Git and trying to push the commit first time to Git remote. When I am using command "git push" it is doing nothing. Seems like git bash is getting hanged and after witing for a long time nothing happens. However git pull is working fine.

Please see the screenshot attached for reference.

[image]

Comment: Try `git push origin -u main` or `git push origin -u main:main`.

Comment: This sounds like https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3294.

Comment: @ElpieKay, No unfortunately both commands didn't work. Still same issue